# can't retreive data from firebase database ( cloud functions )

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

i'm using firebase cloud functions to listen to database value events , this is my code

```
    var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential : firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://*******.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.notifications = functions.database.ref('/chat/{senderID}/{destinationID}/messages/{pushID}')
    .onWrite(event => {        
        var eventSnapshot = event.data;        
        var sender = eventSnapshot.child('sender').val();
        var message = eventSnapshot.child('message').val();
        var destination = eventSnapshot.child('destination').val();        
        if (event.params.senderID === sender) 
            sendMessage(message,sender,destination);    
    }
);

function sendMessage(message, sender, destination) {

    var senderUser = firebase.database().ref('users/'+sender+'/name'); 
    var tokenUser = firebase.database().ref('fcm/'+destination+'/token');
        tokenUser.once('value').then(function(tokenSnapshot) {
            var token = tokenSnapshot.val(); 
                        console.log(token);                        

    }, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});     
}
```

onWrite function execute normally , but `tokenUser.once()` is not executed.

Comment: Is this true ? `event.params.senderID === sender` . Put a few log statements in there with what they output so we can at least know what's happening when you run it.

Comment: sendMessage function is executing i tested it wuth log , so the problem is with data retrieving function

Comment: Ìs there something in your DB at `fcm/'+destination+'/token` ?

Comment: yes it is a correct path

Comment: try `var sender = eventSnapshot.ref.child('sender').val();` `.data` has many properties, one of which is `ref`. You may need to use `.adminRef` if it's data the client can't access.

Comment: Is there actual data in that path ?

Comment: the problem is that tokenUser.once() function is not executing at all , see the code i have log and it didn't execute , i hope you understand the issue.

Comment: yes there is data in the path , but even if there is not , once() function should execute right ?

Comment: I do but if I remember correctly I had the issue where a null value just outputs a line break (instead of undefined or null). So you might want to double check that this is not happening with : `console.log('my token is ', token);`

Comment: where i put this ? outside one() function or inside ? i already have a log inside it and it didn't execute. i also tried to log("test") and it didn't execute

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you try using `tokenUser.once('value')` and don't pass a function, and get directly the `tokenSnapshot`; something like this:

```
tokenUser.once('value').then(tokenSnapshot => {
        var token = tokenSnapshot.val(); 
        console.log(token);                        

});
```

You can pass the function if you use `tokenUser.once()` with a callback; something like this:

```
tokenUser.once('value', function(tokenSnapshot) {
        var token = tokenSnapshot.val(); 
                    console.log(token);                        

}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```